# jQuery ajax complete and release a php file?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a 150 checkboxes on my site and every checkbox with class `.generujbox` call a ajax script:

```
$(".generujbox").click(function(){
    $(".progress-indicator").show();
    var idcheck = $(this).val();

    if($(this).is(":checked")) {

        $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "boxsave.php", 
                data: { genbox: idcheck, liczba: "1" },
                success: function(msg){

                $(".generujbox").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){

                if(msg == \'OK\')
                {
                    $(".progress-indicator").hide();
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $(".progress-indicator").show();
                }});}});

    } else {

     $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "boxsave.php", 
                data: { genbox: idcheck, liczba: "0" },
                success: function(msg){

                $(".generujbox").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){

                if(msg == \'OK\')
                {
                    $(".progress-indicator").hide();
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $(".progress-indicator").show();
                }});}});

    }
    });
```

And everything looks ok. After click on checkbox my `progress-indicator` its working for almost 1second and after this hide (very quickly). And after this I click to next checkbox and i see everything its crashed if i'm not wait a little bit after last ajax call.

How Can i really check when ajax finish everything and release a PHP file with Mysql query ?

I try with `delay(800).hide(0)` but this way I guess that so much time is enough or not ??

Comment: use can use dataType:'json'

Comment: I try with `dataType:"text"` and I see Its very fast and not crashing the website with a lot of checbox.

Answer (score 0):

> $.ajax({
>
> ```
>             type: "POST", 
>             url: "boxsave.php", 
>             data: { genbox: idcheck, liczba: "0" },
>             dataType:'json';
>             success: function(msg){
>
>             }
> ```
>
> });

add **dataType:'json'** in your ajax

In your boxsave.php file add **echo json_encode('success');** after the success of your mysql query.

Comment: it will give json_encode of 'success' except success's value!

Comment: you can send the value you want in json_encode like json_encode('ok') or json_encode($id) and so on

Comment: what is the relation of json_encode with his question?